# MS Access VBA to set scrollbar position of a subform that is a continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form with a subform.  The subform is a continuous form so I can use conditional formatting.  Using controls in a Tab Control, the values of the currently selected record on the subform are changed.  So, I requery the subform to update the subform continuous form to show the updated data.

I can get the correct record re-selected in the subform, but the position of that record in the list jumps to the top of the subform's list instead of maintaining the position it was in prior to the update.

I have tried playing with the CurrentSectionTop values of the subform, but I am not able to correctly maintain the user's selection position within the subform after requerying the subform.

**Is there some way to get the current position of the subform's continuous form's scrollbar position and then set that position in code after the continuous form is requeried?**  (Stephen Lebans' code for doing this (see: http://www.lebans.com/SelectRow.htm) does not work for me because I'm using Access 2013 and his code won't convert to Access 2013).

Here's a sample of what the subform continuous form display might look like to begin with while Record 7 is the current record selected:
    {start of continuous form view}
    [ ] Record 3 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 4 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 5 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 6 in continuous form view
    [>] Record 7 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 8 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 9 in continuous form view
    {end of continuous form view}
    {tab control displays down here below the continuous form subform}

After the subform is requeried, here is what the subform continuous form display looks like, but I want the display to look the same as above; the display should *not* put Record 7 as the top record in the continuous form view since it was the 5th record down in the view originally so I want it to be the 5th record down after the requery:
    {start of continuous form view}
    [>] Record 7 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 8 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 9 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 10 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 11 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 12 in continuous form view
    [ ] Record 13 in continuous form view
    {end of continuous form view}
    {tab control displays down here below the continuous form subform}

Comment: Are there other users adding or deleting records while you are using this form? If so, that can impact gatting back to the 'exact' place.  Have you looked at using the 'SelTop' value to get back?

Comment: Please clarify: You are able to position to the correct record in the subform, but the records scroll so that record is at the top of the scrolling area instead of at its original scroll position?  Also, please supply a link for the specific Stephen Lebans code.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn: Yes, other uses **could** be adding or deleting records, but in my test database, that is not occurring so that does not seem to be the problem.  I tried SelTop but as I recall Acces indicated that was an invalid property whereas CurrentSectionTop did not give that error, but, I'm open to trying to use it if you can head me in the right direction.

Comment: @Tom Robinson: Correct.  I can select the correct record in the subform but the records scroll so that the record is at the top of the scrolling area instead of at its original scroll position (e.g., 5th item in visible scroll area).  Here's a link to the Stephen Lebans code that I could not convert: http://www.lebans.com/SelectRow.htm

Comment: I just downloaded Stephen Lebans' code and converted to Access 2010. I did comment out the code for the 'AfterUpdate' event for the textbox. I am able to click the requery button and it always takes me back to the same row that was at the top -- with one exception: If I go way down the list and establish the 'Current' record, then scroll back up but NOT establish current (i.e. I didn't click on the record) then I am taken back to whatever was the top record.  I don't have 2013 but don't see why you should have a problem. What can't you convert?

Comment: Thanks, @Wayne G. Dunn.  I can't covert it because after unzipping the download, I get a file named: SetGetScrollbarsVer7.mdb.  When I load that mdb into Access 2013 I get the following error message: "Cannot open a database created with a previous version of your application."  If there is a way around that error, can you let me know how to get around it?  If not, is there any way you can get the code from the mdb to me?  I'm not sure how to do something like that on stackoverflow.

Comment: I had to convert the old format database to a newer version. You should be able to convert also... take a look at: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Convert-a-database-to-the-Access-2007-file-format-2fb6ee27-e776-492f-a26e-b2a44c6e8809

Give me a little time and I will post the code that I got from the database.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get Wayne G Dunn's solution working, but I came up with this alternative. It's not wonderful, but it worked for me.

The basic idea is that each record in the continuous form has a position (ie top record showing on the screen is in position 1, regardless which actual record it is).  You have a table that relates those positions, to the Form.currentSectionTop property of each record in the form, so you can figure out what position the current record is in. Then it's relatively straightforward to return to that position after the requery.

Create the table with the positions - this needs to run on startup or somewhere - might need to be more frequent if the user can resize or anything might change the number of records that could be shown in the continuous form.

```
 Public Sub Setup_Positions()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim Position As Long
    Dim currentSectionTop As Long
    Dim lastSectionTop As Long

    sql = "DELETE FROM tblRecordPosition"
    currentdb.execute sql

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst

    Position = 1

    Call Set_NoUpdate

    With Forms("frmMain").Controls("frmContinuousSubForm").Form
        currentSectionTop = .currentSectionTop
        Do While currentSectionTop <> lastSectionTop

            'record previous sectiontop
            lastSectionTop = currentSectionTop



            'write it into the table
            sql = "INSERT INTO tblRecordPosition (Position, CurrentSectionTop) " & _
                "SELECT " & Position & ", " & _
                currentSectionTop
            CurrentDb.Execute sql

            'update to next position and record the 'last' one, move to next record. When we've run out of visible ones, the last and current will be the same.
            Position = Position + 1
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
            'get new current sectiontop
            currentSectionTop = .currentSectionTop
        Loop

    End With

    Call Set_NoUpdateOff

End Sub
```

Set up global variables and a couple of functions to maintain them.  The 'NoUpdateRequired' variable is optional - I use it to prevent unnecessary stuff running all the time.

```
 Public NoUpdateRequired As Boolean
Public Position As Long

Public Sub Set_NoUpdate()
    NoUpdateRequired = True
End Sub

Public Sub Set_NoUpdateOff()
    NoUpdateRequired = False
End Sub
```

Create this function to convert between the property you can measure, and the actual position:

```
 Public Function Get_Position(Optional InputCurrentSectionTop As Long) As Long
Dim currentSectionTop As Long
Dim Position As Long

If InputCurrentSectionTop > 0 Then
    currentSectionTop = InputCurrentSectionTop
Else
    currentSectionTop = Forms("frmMain").Controls("frmContinuousSubForm").Form.currentSectionTop

End If

Position = Nz(ELookup("Position", "tblRecordPosition", "CurrentSectionTop = " & currentSectionTop), 0)

Get_Position = Position

End Function
```

In the current event of the continuous form, you need this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
   If NoUpdateRequired = False Then
       Position = Get_Position
   End If
End Sub
```

And finally, in the bit where you want your refresh to happen, you need this:

```
Public Sub Refresh_ContinuousSubForm()

'All this problem goes away if you can use Refresh instead of Requery, but if you have a few things editting the underlying table, you must use requery to avoid 'another user has changed the data' errors.  
'However, this then causes the form to jump
'back to the first record instead of keeping the current record selected.  To get around this, the following has been employed:
'the .seltop property allows you to select the top selected record (in most cases, only one record is selected).  This is recorded before the refresh, and
'the form set back to that after the refresh. However, this puts the selected record at the top of the screen - confusing when you're working down a list.
'The .currentSectionTop property measures the number of twips from the selected record to the top of the screen - and correlates to which position in the list
'of 25 records in the bottom pane.  tblRecordPosition converts between the twips to the actual position (recorded when the database is opened).

'The key to all this is that going back to the right record using .seltop only puts the record at the top of the screen IF the record wasn't already visible on the screen.
'But GoToRecord, if used when you're already at the top of the screen, will push the records down the screen as you move backward (upward) through them.
'So we go to the right record, and it will probably be at the top of the screen because of the requery.  Then we push them down the screen back to the original position
'using GoToRecord, but now we're on the wrong record.  Then we return to the right record using .seltop, and because it's already on the screen, it won't move position.

Dim startSeltop As Long
Dim newSectionTop As Long
Dim newPosition As Long
Dim startPosition As Long
Dim recordsToMove As Long
'Also global variable Position (long) which is recorded in the form's current event

Call Set_NoUpdate

startPosition = Position

With Forms("frmMain").Controls("frmContinuousSubForm").Form
    .Painting = False 'stops the screen flickering between
    startSeltop = .SelTop 'records which record we're on.  Position represents where that was showing on the screen.

    .Requery 'does the requery

    .SelTop = startSeltop 'sets us back to the correct record
    newSectionTop = .currentSectionTop 'measures in twips which position it's in (usually 1)
    newPosition = Get_Position(newSectionTop) 'converts that to the position
    recordsToMove = startPosition - newPosition 'calculates how many records to move - moving records using GoToRecord moves the position as well

    If recordsToMove > 0 Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious, recordsToMove 'moves back enough records to push our record to the right place on the screen
    End If

    .SelTop = startSeltop 'now sets back to the correct record
    .Painting = True 'turns the screen painting back on
End With

Call Set_NoUpdateOff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a subset of the code found on Stephen Lebans' website: http://www.lebans.com/SelectRow.htm .  That link has a link to a zipped version of an Access database with all the code to handle multiple scenarios, however the database is an older version and needs to be converted. Mr Leban's code does far more than what is included here, but I am only using this code to solve one specific issue.

(A) Create a Class Module named 'clsSetRow' and paste in the following code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mSelTop As Long
Private mCurrentSectionTop As Long

Public Property Get SelTop() As Long
SelTop = mSelTop
End Property

Public Property Let SelTop(x As Long)
mSelTop = x
End Property


Public Property Get CurrentSectionTop() As Long
CurrentSectionTop = mCurrentSectionTop
End Property

Public Property Let CurrentSectionTop(x As Long)
mCurrentSectionTop = x
End Property
```

(B) In your module for your form, include the following at the top:

```
Private SR As clsSetRow
Dim lCurRec As Long
```

(C) Add the following Event Handlers and code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set SR = New clsSetRow
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Current()
' This event can be called during the Form Load event prior to the init of
' our class so we must test for this.
If Not SR Is Nothing Then
    SR.SelTop = Me.SelTop
    SR.CurrentSectionTop = Me.CurrentSectionTop
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()    ' OR JUST USE THE BEFOREINSERT
    lCurRec = Me.CurrentRecord
    'Debug.Print "After Insert, Current: " & Me.CurrentRecord
End Sub
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)   ' OR JUST USE THE AFTERINSERT
    lCurRec = Me.CurrentRecord
    'Debug.Print "Before Insert, Current: " & Me.CurrentRecord
End Sub
```

(D) Wherever you want to reposition (i.e. after a REQUERY), add the following line of code:

```
 DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acGoTo, lCurRec
```

(E) To test this, just add a command button that will 'Requery and then GoToRecord'.

NOTE: Simply scrolling up or down using the scrollbar will NOT save the row of where you are! You need to establish a 'current record' for this to reposition.

Good Luck!  And thank you Stephen Lebans for the code!

Comment: Thank you so much @Wayne G. Dunn. It's close, but... Problems: (1) since the form to reposition is a subform, DoCmd.GoToRecord gives error that object isn't open; (2) when I rewrite code using SelTop, then I can control the subform position & select correct record on the 1st requery but not requeries after that; (3) if I run alternate code using .bookmark on 2nd, 3rd...requeries, I can correctly reposition & select the correct record, but get errors when the selected record is in the 1st or 2nd position in the subform list view or when the selected record is scrolled out of view when requeried

Comment: Where is the code that requeries - Main or Sub? For my testing, I have a button on the subform that will requery then GOTO - and that works fine. What does your code look like?

Comment: thanks again.  The requery cannot happen on the subform itself, it happens from actions on the main form.  Actually, it happens based on a button press in a different subform and that subform is on a tab control on the main form.  Yes, I could get a test form to work when the requery was on the actual subform, but once the requery happens outside the subform it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What if requery is done from the subform itself, then what could we do in this case? I am calling requery from the subform itself and then when I call this "GoToRecord" line, I get this error, The Object "x" isn't open. So How can I resolve this error in this case?

Comment: Change the '.gotorecord' line to be:         If CurrentProject.AllForms(Me.Name).IsLoaded Then
            DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acGoTo, lCurRec
        Else
            Debug.Print "FORM NOT LOADED!!"
        End If

Comment: I got an error saying "An expression in argument 4 has an invalid value". What did i do wrong?

Comment: Please post the values that you are passing for the four arguments